# Java to *get* mail from SMTP sevrer

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I'm trying to **get** an email from exchange SMTP server (port 25).
all the examples i saw are to send an email with SMTP while i would like to get (read) an email.
I wrote a code using JAVAMail that get email with impas that work perfect but in the last mooment the demand change to use SMTP for incoming mail.

**Java code for IMAP incoming mail**

```
 public void getAttachment() throws MessagingException, IOException {
        properties.setProperty("exchange server host",host);
        properties.put("smtp.gmail.auth", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                }
                }
        );

        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        try {
            logger.info(String.format("Going to get connection to exchange server %s for user %s " ,host, user));
            store.connect(host, user, password);
        }
        catch (MessagingException ex){
            logger.error(String.format("Unable to connect exchange server {}", host) + ex.getMessage());
            logger.error(ex.getStackTrace());
        }
        Folder inboxFolder = store.getFolder("inbox");
        inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        // search for all "unseen" messages
        Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
        FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
        Message[] message = inboxFolder.search(unseenFlagTerm);
```

Can someone please advise for getting mail with SMTP protocol and not with IMAP?
can it be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

[SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is for a client to **send** email to a server.

In order for a client to **receive** email from a server, you need to use protocols like [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) (Post Office Protocol) or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) (Internet Message Access Protocol).

Actually, the Wikipedia page for SMTP says as much:

> User-level [email clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_client) typically use SMTP only for sending messages to a mail server for relaying, typically submit outgoing email to the mail server on port 587 or 465 as per [RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314). For retrieving messages, [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) and [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) are standard, but proprietary servers also often implement proprietary protocols, e.g., [Exchange ActiveSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync).

Comment: ok thanks. but in fact the exchnage server configured to use SMTP for both incoming and outgoing emails. how can it be?

Comment: @Asfbar Because Microsoft Exchange Server implements all of those protocols, in addition to some proprietary protocols.